# Shadow Image on Navigation bar when scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm finding I'm able to set the shadow image on the navigation bar, but I only want to set it when I'm scrolling and not able to find how to do this. any help appreciated!!

Comment: Have you tried any code, Then post it.

Comment: A screenshot would be helpful too.

Answer (score 1):

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let offset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    if offset <= 0 {
        // scroll view is at the top, disable shadow
    } else {
        // scroll view has positive offset, enable shadow
    }
    print(offset) // if you aren't familiar with how it works
}
```

You can access this delegate method from either a `UIScrollView` or a `UITableView` as the latter is a subclass of the former.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code with [scrollViewDidScroll(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate/1619392-scrollviewdidscroll):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIScrollViewDelegate {

   @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       tableView.dataSource = self
       tableView.delegate = self

       tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
       tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
   }


   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

       let cell = UITableViewCell()
       cell.textLabel?.text = "Hello"

       return cell
   }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return 10
   }

   func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

       guard let navBar = navigationController?.navigationBar else {
           return
       }

       if scrollView.contentOffset.y > navBar.frame.height {
           addShadow(navBar)
       } else {
           deleteShadow(navBar)
       }
   }

   func addShadow(_ view: UIView) {
       view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
       view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 6.0)
       view.layer.masksToBounds = false
       view.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0
       view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
   }

   func deleteShadow(_ view: UIView) {
       view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0.0)
       view.layer.shadowRadius = 0
       view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0
   }
}
```